# Get URL parameter using Spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have Spring application,I want to set parameter in URL and forward to URL.
For example,I click "Show detail" in index.html.Then go to /employees/show/1111.
ShowController.java get 1111.Now I click "show detail",result is white page error.
And I set break point ShowController.java,break point cannot was not working.
Where I should fix it?

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employees/show/{employee.empId}/")
public class ShowController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

    @GetMapping
    public String details(@RequestParam("empId") String empId, Model model) {
        Employee employee = empService.getEmployeeInfo(Long.parseLong(empId)); // break point at this row
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "view/show";
    }
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="employee : ${employees}">
            <td th:text="${employee.empId}"></td>
            <td th:text="${employee.empName}"></td>
            <td><a th:href="@{'/employees/show/' + ${employee.empId}}">Show detail</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>
```

show.html

```
<body>
            <div th:text="${employee.empId}"></div>
            <div th:text="${employee.empName}"></div>
</body>
```

This folder structure.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whats is your project folder stucture and what is the url resolved on browser url?

Comment: I pased folder structure and url resolved on browser url is "http://localhost:8080/employees/show/922612144"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the url. You are using `/employees/show/{employee.empId}/` as a base url. And `@GetMapping`is not mapped to any url, so it takes the exact url from `@RequestMapping("/employees/show/{employee.empId}/")`.

`@RequestParam` is to extract query parameters, form parameters, and even files from the request, while `@PathVariable` is used to tell Spring that part of the URI path is a value you want passed to your method.

So, in your case it seems mixed, you are using `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employees/show/{employee:.*}/") //since spring will skip anything after a dot(.)
....

@GetMapping
public String details(@PathVariable("empId") String empId, Model model) {....}
```

Comment: I solved.I confused how to use RequestParam and PathVariable.Thank you.